# catch block gives me no match for operator error

Tags: c++, exception, stl, try-catch, overloading

I am trying to catch the exception like below -

```
try {

} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
    cout << "An exception occurred when executing query. " << ex << endl;
}
```

But everytime I am getting this error -

`no match for operator<< in std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >((* & std::cout), ((const char*)"An exception occurred when executing query. ")) << ex`

Any idea what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
cout << "An exception occurred when executing query. " << ex.what() << endl;
```

The `<<` operator is not overloaded in the `exception` class.

Comment: Thanks... Is this the right way to catch the exception? As I will be using logger to log the exceptions afterwards.. For now I am using cout

Comment: You should try to catch specific exceptions so that you know the type of error occurring. `catch(exception& e)` will catch every possible subclass of `exception`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is (trying to) telling you that an `operator<<(std::ostream&, std::exception const&)` is not declared.

Answer (score 1):

There is no overload for operator `<<` that matches `std::exception`.  Use `ex.what()` instead.  `what()` returns a `char*` which `<<` understands.
Reference:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/what/